# Not getting the zipcode using geocode and map API for India

Tags: java, android, google-maps, location

I am not getting the zipcode from both geocoder and the map API in Android.

Geocoder returns null value, I am using the following code:

```
List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(12.45454, 80.26565, 1);
addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
```

Alternatively I am trying the below also,

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=12.45454,80.26565&sensor=true

The response it self I am not getting the postal code.

Comment: As you can see from the results from the link you've posted "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE". It means that google is not 100% sure it found the address you were looking for. If the location_type is "ROOFTOP" the result is more accurate. So I guess you won't be able to get postal code unless the type is "ROOFTOP"

Comment: So how can i get the status "ROOFTOP", By which way i should provide the inputs

Comment: Unfortunately if "ROOFTOP" is not return it means there are no accurate results for location you are requesting.